# Google Sign UI Delegate on multiple view controller ERROR

Tags: swift, delegates, google-signin

I'm getting error while implementing google signin ui delegate in multiple view controller,

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'uiDelegate must either be a |UIViewController| or implement the |signIn:presentViewController:| and |signIn:dismissViewController:| methods from |GIDSignInUIDelegate|.'
```

and i can't able to implement as per my requirement

**In Detail:**

I'm implementing google signin delegate for login and signup in my application.

for login - login view controller
and for signup - signup view controller

i have done the stuffs that google developer site says in my appdelegate.swift.

and successfully implemented the Google Signin UI Delegate in login view controller and ran the app. its done.

Now, tried to implement the same in the signup view controller and finally resulted in app crash.

**Need to know:**

Can I call **`GIDSignInUIDelegate`** in multiple view controllers.

Can I able to get logged in user detail in view controller beyond the appdelegate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543729/google-sign-in-api/36545047#36545047

Comment: super @sahil  i needed a solution like this