# facebook openurl for login in ios 9 method ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, ios9, openurl

I have both facebook and gmail integration in my app but as soon as I add the open url function for gmail login the facebook login stops working.
I have this code for open url in my app

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    var shouldOpen :Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,openURL: url,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)

    shouldOpen = shouldOpen ? shouldOpen : GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                                                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                                                annotation: annotation)

    return shouldOpen

}
```

This works fine with the facebook login but when I add openurl method for gmail for ios 9 the problem occures i.e. after facebook login we don't redirect back to the app. In simulator the white screen shows in safari. the code for the gmail login for ios 9

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {

        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                    sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String?,
                                                    annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
    }
    return true
}
```

If I  comment out the above code the facebook login works correctly I guess the problem is that I have to return boolean for openurl of facebook in ios 9 as well. But I don't know what to do with this ?
TIA

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543729/google-sign-in-api/36545047#36545047

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my answer i need to implement both methods of openurl Like this

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    var shouldOpen :Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,openURL: url,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)

    shouldOpen = shouldOpen ? shouldOpen : GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                                                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                                                annotation: annotation)
    return shouldOpen

}

func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        var shouldOpen :Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            app,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String,
            annotation: nil)

        shouldOpen = shouldOpen ? shouldOpen : GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String?,
                                                                                    annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])

        return shouldOpen
    }
    return true
}
```

i just need to check for facebook open url method for ios 9 as well

Edit for swift 3.0 the function changed

```
private func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {


    return  FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,open: url as URL!,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)

}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 9.0 , *){
     return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: "UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey", annotation: nil)   

    }

return true
}
```

Comment: This also works for iOS 10 Beta with the FBSDKLoginButton; the method with the sourceApplication is deprecated though. Used only the second one.

Comment: This is the one I was looking for. +1 for using Ternary operator. However it will hurt if I use one more url scheme :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried @Aruk k answer but didn't work for me

I have also faced this problem from past 1 month.Followed all the steps and tutorials but nothing worked. I was integrating facebook login with firebase in ios 10 swift 3. Finally, I m able to successfully implement it. I corrected it by making following changed in AppDelegate file.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FIRApp.configure()
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
          return true
    }


    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
        -> Bool {
            var shouldOpen :Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,  open: url, sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!,annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
            return shouldOpen
    }

    // for iOS below 9.0
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        var shouldOpen :Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,open: url as URL!,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)
        return shouldOpen
    }
```

I Hope it might help others

tested on ios 10.2 Emulator, iPhone 6 Plus running with 10.2

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4. Xcode 9. iOS 11. Google SignIn + Facebook SignIn. AppDelegate.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    var signedIn: Bool = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

    signedIn = signedIn ? signedIn : FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

    return signedIn
}

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {

    var signedIn: Bool = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

    signedIn = signedIn ? signedIn : FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: nil)

    return signedIn
}
```